# Randomly move the uibutton some 8 static position using timer in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have doubt in to moving uibutton randomly from one position to another position, the position's are static. There are totall eight positions. Using timer i will call dis method.

Comment: Have a look at the implicit animations available through use of [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

- save those 8 positions in 8 CGRects.
- then generate a random number between 1 and 8 using `int r = arc4random() % 8`;.
- using `switch` statement set the `CGRect` of the button depending on r.

Answer (score 0):

in your .h file add this:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *framesArray;
```

in your .m file add these:

in your **viewDidLoad** method:

```
    _timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeButtonPositions) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

   _framesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_1, y_1, w_1, h_1)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_2, y_2, w_2, h_2)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_3, y_3, w_3, h_3)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_4, y_4, w_4, h_4)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_5, y_5, w_5, h_5)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_6, y_6, w_6, h_6)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_7, y_7, w_7, h_7)],[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(x_8, y_8, w_8, h_8)], nil];
```

When you want to start animate the **changingButton**, do it like this:

```
[_timer fire];
```

and add this method:

```
- (void) changeButtonPositions{
    int number = arc4random() % 8;
    changingButton.frame = [[_framesArray objectAtIndex:number] CGRectValue];
}
```

when you want to finish animating, do

```
[_timer invalidate];
```

Comment: Hi have tried this,its not working fine please help me out for dis problem.

Comment: isn't it animating properly?

Comment: i have changed little bit in NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval   i have changed like dis NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval then its animating correctly